# Needed guidance for MySql select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi i have a table like this

```
Activity     Date
---------------------
0          2012-11-20
1          2012-11-20
1          2012-11-20
1          2012-11-21
1          2012-11-21
0          2012-11-22
```

I need to select the record as

```
 Day-wise total   0's    1's    Date  
------------------------------------------
     3             1      2     2012-11-20
     2             0      2     2012-11-21
     1             1      0     2012-11-22
```

Comment: I got the day-wise count using `group by date`, need to get `0's` and `1's`.(try to help instead of asking question like what you have tried?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a `GROUP BY date`, `COUNT(Activity)` to get Day-wise total and a `CASE` expression to pivot the values of 1's and 0's. I used `SUM` here but it acts like `COUNT` like so:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(Activity) AS "Day-wise total",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0's",
  SUM(CASE WHEN Activity = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "1's",
  `Date` AS "Date"
FROM Table
GROUP BY `Date`;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b429/6)

Comment: @LearneR - Its my pleasure, you are welcome any time. Glad I could help.